# Openlayers 3 Max Extent

Tags: openlayers, extents

I want to restrict where the user can pan on the map, but I can't seem to find any resources that tell how to set the max extent of a map view in OpenLayers 3. I know there was a solution in OpenLayers 2. Is it possible in the new version?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This can simply be done by defining `extent` in the View object. eg

```
var view = new ol.View({
    ...
    extent: [minx,miny,maxx,maxy]
    ...
});
var map = new ol.Map({
    ...
    view: view,
    ...
});
```

Comment: But in http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/apidoc/ol.View.html there is not such option

Comment: A lot is not documented, or experimental and only visible when stable is not checked

Comment: This isn't a real extent. It just keeps the extents within view, meaning there is ugly white space all around the extent.

Comment: Meanwhile, `extent` has become a proper documented feature: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_View-View.html (as of writing, "latest" = v5.3.0)

Answer (score 4):

Another option is:

```
...
var map = new ol.Map({
          layers: [...],
          overlays: [...],
          target: document.getElementById('map'),
          view: new ol.View({
             center: ol.proj.transform([minx,miny,maxx,maxy], 
                     'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
             zoom: ...,    
             maxZoom: ..., 
             minZoom: ..., 
             extent: ol.proj.transform([minx-n,miny-n,maxx+n,maxy+n], 
                     'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')
             })
        });
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Like Ragnagord already pointed out it is necessary to set the `extent` in your `ol.view`.

Depending on what you want to refer to the easiest way is to get the extent directly from your desired projection (`ol.proj.Projection`) or layer (any class of `ol.layer`) using the `getExtent()` function. In case of EPSG:3857 this works:

```
var map = new ol.Map({
    ...
    view: new ol.View({
        ...
        extent: ol.proj.get("EPSG:3857").getExtent()
  })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I have to point out if we consider the map projection, in my case between WGS84 and Spherical Mercator, there is an alternative with [`ol.proj.transformExtent`](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.proj.html#.transformExtent). An answer was found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22805580/4526730). 
Extent is assigned as follows:

```
var map = new ol.Map({
   .
   .
   .
   view: new ol.View({
        extent:  ol.proj.transformExtent([minx, miny, maxx, maxy], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
         .
         .
         .
        )}
)}
```