# OpenLayers 3 don't go beyond given coordinates

Tags: openlayers, extents

In [Openlayers 3 Max Extent](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/118383/openlayers-3-max-extent) there is mentioned how to set a max extent. But how can I set coordinates in such a way that it is not possible to drag the map beyond the some given coordinates?

Extent is used to make sure that at least one corner of the rectangle is still in visible, but I want that you can't even drag beyond the rectangles borders.

Comment: duplicate? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/118383/openlayers-3-max-extent?lq=1 EDIT: just tried that answer out and now I see what you mean.

Comment: Was this ever figured out?