# How to not allow drag map out of window with OpenLayers 3?

Tags: openlayers

I can drag the map out of window.

See this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/zykkxa6b/). Can I disable these borders not allowing drag the map out of window?

[image]

Comment: See this: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/118383/openlayers-3-max-extent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. First of all you are using a very old version of OL3. 3.0.0 while currenlty version 3.11.2 is running.
2. The solution @Zoltan suggests will prevent your map to move the map center outside the supplied extent. I am not sure whether this is going to help you.
3. A combination of @zoltan suggestion + a maxZoom parameter maybe will solve your case.
4. The example you provide is wrapping the tiles horizontally. As a result your map width is too big compared to the height. For the specific layer you use `new ol.source.MapQuest` there is no option to disable it. But for other tile layers like OSM you have the option to disable x wrapping. like so

   ```
    new ol.layer.Tile({
     source: new ol.source.OSM({
       wrapX: false
     })
   })
   ```

now using this case and a maxZoom will solve your problem.

5. If none of the above feets your case, cosider to style the div you use to place your map and give a lowest heigh so that it feets with the map.