# Prevent panning and zooming beyond map edges in OpenLayers 4.6.4

Tags: openlayers

I have a web page with map that is using OpenLayers 4.6.4 and I want to prevent the user from panning or zooming beyond the edge of the map, like this:

[image: OpenLayers4 <div> panned beyond map data]

There are plenty of answers for this for OL3, but that is very different than OL4. Items likes "restrictedExtent" that existed in OL3 are no longer there in OL4.

The only customizations I have added to the map are the fullscreen and scale controls and an onclick handler as I am still new to OL & GIS (though not to web development).

OL is getting the data from a GeoServer instance via WMS if that makes any difference.

Comment: You can set the `extent` within the `View` config. This will set the extent that constrains the center, in other words, center cannot be set outside this extent. http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.View.html

Comment: I set the extents, but that does not prevent panning like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've run into this situation and used the following code:

Just after map is initialized:

```js
const nc_array = map.getView().calculateExtent(map.getSize());
const nc_s = nc_array[1];
const nc_w = nc_array[0];
const nc_n = nc_array[3];
const nc_e = nc_array[2];

map.on('moveend', function() {
    /* uses nc_array data (nc_w, nc_s, nc_e, nc_n) from initial map setup*/
    var ext_array = map.getView().calculateExtent(map.getSize());
    var ext_s = ext_array[1];
    var ext_w = ext_array[0];
    var ext_n = ext_array[3];
    var ext_e = ext_array[2];
    if(ext_s < nc_s) {
        var now_s = view.getZoom();
        view.fit([ext_w, nc_s, ext_e, ext_n+(nc_s-ext_s)]);
        map.getView().setZoom(now_s);
    }
    if(ext_w < nc_w) {
        var now_w = view.getZoom();
        view.fit([nc_w, ext_s, ext_e+(nc_w-ext_w), ext_n]);
        map.getView().setZoom(now_w);
    }
    if(ext_n > nc_n) {
        var now_n = view.getZoom();
        view.fit([ext_w, ext_s-(ext_n-nc_n), ext_e, nc_n]);
        map.getView().setZoom(now_n);
    }
    if(ext_e > nc_e) {
        var now_e = view.getZoom();
        view.fit([ext_w-(ext_e-nc_e), ext_s, nc_e, ext_n]);
        map.getView().setZoom(now_e);
    }
});
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: If you have the latest version of OpenLayers, you don't need to make such code - you just need to set the extent attribute to the map.view

Answer (score 2):

In order to restrict the panning of the map to some area use the ol.View attribute extent. 
To restrict the zoom level use the ol.View attributes maxZoom & minZoom.

see https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/154882/110012

Comment: Setting the extent does not prevent panning beyond the edges.

Comment: The map can still be dragged, for example, to the bottom right so that the centre point of the canvas is, effectively 180°W 90°N like here http://image.ibb.co/jjf1jG/image.png (or what ever your western and northern reaches are)

Comment: For this to work, you need the latest version of OpenLayers.